# How to achieve this in SQL Server and Postgresql

Tags: sql

I/P

```
country Status
ind     y
ind     y
ind     y
us      y
us      y
us      y
uk      y
uk      y
uk      n
```

o/p

```
country Status  Flag
ind     y       1
ind     y       1
ind     y       1
us      y       1
us      y       1
us      y       1
uk      y       0
uk      y       0
uk      n       0
```

Comment: Achieve *what*? Which databases, which versions? The title and tags contain different products. MySQL != SQL Server != PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the flag?

Comment: This question should be closed by now! Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: `0 = COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'n' THEN 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS flag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems want `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM table t1 
                          WHERE t1.country = t.country AND t1.Status = 'n'
                         ) 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 
        END) AS Flag
FROM table t;
```

You can also use *window* function :

```
SELECT t.*, 
      (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN [STATUS] = 'n' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY) = 1 
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 
       END) AS Flag
FROM table t;
```